# Problemas al crear mi carpeta .git en GIT

Tags: git

Tengo un problema al darle `git init` en mi `git bash` no me crea la carpeta llamada .git para empezar a utilizar los demás comandos, alguien que conozca la razón me ayudaría mucho. :)

Comment: Si no te devuelve un error, posiblemente la esté creando. Sólo ten en cuenta que es un directorio oculto (los que empiezan con un `.`, son ocultos)

Comment: intenta ejecutar git status, si la respuesta dice que no es un repositorio es que no se ha creado, pero si lo ejecuta bien, quiere decir que se creo pero como te mencionan no esta visible

Comment: ¿cómo miras si te la ha creado? Si miras con un `ls` no la mostrará (porque `ls` no muestra cualquier archivo o carpeta cuyo nombre comienza por punto). Si quieres forzar a que te lo muestre debes usar `ls -a`. Si lo miras desde el explorador de archivos de Windows sí deberías verla.

Answer (score 0):

¿Cual es el error que te lanza? si no te lanza nada o si te aparece algo como

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /directory/of/work
```

Entonces ya esta creado el .git y pasa que no ves los archivos ocultos como el caso de .git, para verlos en linux o mac necesitas pulsar ls -a para verlos y en Windows en la barra de herramientas aparece "Mostrar archivos ocultos".